# Dynamically Modify CSS from GWT

Tags: css, gwt

for example I have a css in test.css given below.

```
.test {

  top:100px;

 }
```

how can i increment top property from GWT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g. you can [retrieve](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#getStyle%28%29) the Style of the element and alter that.
other type of widgets might have other functionalities

Comment: thank you i tested nice shot , but i previously wrote some gwt program
such as changing setAttribute("style","top:101px;"),in FF,chrome it is OK but in IE it stays its default position but now i dont use setAttribute ,instead i use getElement().getStyle().setTop("101",Unit.PX);

Answer (score 1):

You can hold value in memory and just set it at any time you need it via runtime substitution which is built-in GWT feature.

```
@eval userBackground com.module.UserPreferences.getUserBackground();
div {
   background: userBackground;
}

public class UserPreferences {
    public static String getUserBackground() {
        return "#FF0000";
    }
}
```

Please check GWT specs:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#Runtime_substitution